# Check if a text file exists in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to check if a text file exists on a site on a different domain. The URL could be:

```
http://sub.somedomain.com/blah/atextfile.txt
```

I need to do this from code behind. I am trying to use the `HttpWebRequest` object, but not sure how to do it.

**EDIT: I am looking for a light weight way of doing this as I'll be executing this logic every few seconds**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                       "http://sub.somedomain.com/blah/atextfile.txt");

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // FILE EXISTS!
}
response.Close();
```

Comment: You might also want to set the HttpWebRequest.Timeout property to a low value, if you're doing it every few seconds. The default is 100 seconds, you probably don't want to wait that long if the file is unavailable or server is unresponsive.

Comment: It appears that requestGetResponse() throws an exception if the file does not exist? The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse

Comment: I'm guessing this could be wrapped in a using block to make it a little mo' nice (no Close() required).

Comment: @User102533: what's the exception?  That could be your answer right there.

Comment: I'm guessing it's just a generic "WebException".  Is that good enough?  Or do you really need to know if the file isn't there, and take a different action if the server returns some other kind of error?

Comment: I would rather not the code throw the exception everytime I check for this. If there's no other way, I guess I could wrap it up in a try catch block but would be doing it half heartedly

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the method used here:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/2c13cafc-be1c-4dd8-9129-f82f59991517/the-lowly-http-head-reque.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead("http://does.not.exist.com/textfile.txt"))
        {
        }
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```